# How to ensure arrays have proper dimensions for softmax layer in tensorflow python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am building my first neural net from scratch with tensorflow and am getting stuck. I am trying to solve a multiclass text sequence classification problem (3 classes). I have been following tf tutorials, but I am not sure what is going wrong.

My input data is as follows:

*samples* = list of strings of text sequences ranging from 1 to 295 words long

*labels* = list of 295 integers (one per sample) that are either 0, 1 or 2.

My code:

```html
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras import preprocessing
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
import numpy as np
```

```html
# tokenize and vectorize text data to prepare for embedding
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(samples)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(samples)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print(f'Found {len(word_index)} unique tokens.')
# one_hot_results = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(samples, mode='binary')

# setting variables
num_samples = len(word_index) # 1499
# Input_dim: This is the size of the vocabulary in the text data.
input_dim = num_samples # 1499
# output_dim: This is the size of the vector space in which words will be embedded.
output_dim = 32 # recommended by tutorial
# max_sequence_length: This is the length of input sequences
max_sequence_length = len(max(sequences, key=len)) # 295
# train/test index splice variable
training_samples = round(len(samples)*.8)

data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_sequence_length)
# preprocess labels
labels = np.asarray(labels)
indices = np.arange(data.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
data = data[indices] # shape (499, 295)
labels = to_categorical(labels, num_classes=None, dtype='float32')


# Create test/train data (80% train, 20% test)
x_train = data[:training_samples]
y_train = labels[:training_samples]
x_test = data[training_samples:]
y_test = labels[training_samples:]

# creating embedding layer with shape [amount of unique words in samples, length of longest sample in samples]
# embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index)+1, len(max(samples, key=len)))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, input_length=max_sequence_length))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train,
          y_train,
          epochs=10,
          batch_size=32,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Essentially, I am just trying to feed in my text data as tokens into an embedding layer, and dense layer, and then the 3 node softmax layer for classification. When I run this, I get the following error:

```html
Found 1499 unique tokens.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:66: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:541: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4432: The name tf.random_uniform is deprecated. Please use tf.random.uniform instead.

Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 295, 32)           47968     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 295, 32)           1056      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 295, 3)            99        
=================================================================
Total params: 49,123
Trainable params: 49,123
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py:793: The name tf.train.Optimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.Optimizer instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3576: The name tf.log is deprecated. Please use tf.math.log instead.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-94cb754412aa> in <module>()
     49           epochs=10,
     50           batch_size=32,
---> 51           validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    129                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    130                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 131                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    132                 if not check_batch_axis:
    133                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (399, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need more information to solve the problem you're facing. But I can tell you what's wrong.

You have a target set of size `[399, 3]`. However, your model summary looks like follows.

```
Model: "sequential_9"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_5 (Embedding)      (None, 295, 50)           5000      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 295, 32)           1632      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 295, 3)            99        
=================================================================
```

You see that even though you have a list of labels with 2 dimensions, your model expects a set of targets with 3 dimensions.

Now solving that, well... that's a different story. Let's see our options.

### You have exactly 295 words in each sample and 399 samples like that.

If you are 100% certain that each sequence in your data is 295 elements long, you can simply solve this problem by adding a `Flatten()` layer. However, keep in mind that this will increase the amount of parameters in your model with,

- The length of your sequence
- The embedding size

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, input_length=max_sequence_length, input_shape=(295,)))
#model.add(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

### You have 399 samples but each sample can have any number of items between 1-295

Now your input can have varying lengths. Therefore, you need to define `input_shape` argument to the first layer accordingly.

The second problem is that your `Embedding` layer produces varying size outputs (depending on the sequence length). But the dense layer cannot take variable size inputs. Therefore you need some "squashing" transformation inbetween. One that usually works well with `Embeddings` is taking the mean. You can do this the following way.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, input_length=max_sequence_length, input_shape=(None,)))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this `Dense` layer in your model which is supposed to be trained and generates the classes:

```py
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

So it expects to get 3-dimensional outputs. However, your dataset has 1-dimensional labels with 3 different values `(0,1,2)`. You can easily convert your classes to categorical vectors. For example you can generate these vectors in your dataset:

- 0 --- `(1,0,0)`
- 1 --- `(0,1,0)`
- 2 --- `(0,0,1)`

If you want to automate this process, you can use Keras `to_categorical` function:

```py
keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=None, dtype='float32')
```

For more information about `to_categorical` visit Keras documentation [here](https://keras.io/utils/)